# Simple php ajax pagination, how to get request url

Tags: php, ajax

**UPDATE 2 18.05.2020**

(AJAX) URL pagination on refresh + window.history.replaceState + window.history.pushState +location.pathname

After refresh [Test3](http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/2020_pagination_1/public/page=5)

[image]

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      load_data(1);      
      function load_data(page)  
      {          
        $('#load_data').html('<div id="status" style="" ></div>');
        $.ajax({
                url:"pagination2.php",  
                method:"POST", 
                data:{page:page},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#load_data').html(data);
                } 
           }); 
      }  

      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(event) 
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var page = $(this).attr("id"); 
            load_data(page);
            //Now push PAGE to URL
            window.history.pushState({page}, `Selected: ${page}`, `${ 'page=' + page}`)
            //window.history.pushState({page}, `Selected: ${page}`, `./selected=${page}`)
            return event.preventDefault(); 
      });
            window.addEventListener('popstate', e => {
            var page = $(this).attr("id");
            load_data(e.state.page);
            console.log('popstate error!');
    });

        //history.replaceState({page: null}, 'Default state', './');
        var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
        params.set('page');
        window.history.replaceState({}, "", decodeURIComponent(`${location.pathname}?${params}`));
 });
```

I've built a PHP AJAX pagination that works -> [ajax pagination](http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/2020_pagination_2/public/).

I'm new to jQuery/ajax. I am not able to understand the usage the url parameter.

My output: `pagination2.php`

I want the output: `pagination2.php/page=2,3,4....`

Any ideas?

My code **index.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
      load_data(1);   
      function load_data(page)  
      {          
        $('#load_data').html('<div id="status" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'pagination2';
        $.ajax({
                url:"pagination2.php",  
                method:"POST", 
                data:{page:page}, 
                complete: function(){
                    alert(this.url)
                },
                success: function(data){  
                     $('#load_data').html(data);
                }, 
           })  
      }  

      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(event) 
        {
            event.preventDefault();  
            var page = $(this).attr("id"); 
            load_data(page);
            return event.preventDefault();
      });
 });
```

**pagination2.php**

```
echo "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='".$i."'>".$i."</span>";
```

**UPDATE1** 
I added: history.pushState but I don't know if this method is correct. I can manipulate next - back /selected=2, selected=3... But, another problem arises, after refresh selected disappears. [Test 2](http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/2020_pagination_1/public/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

      load_data(1);  
      function load_data(page)   
      {   
        $('#load_data').html('<div id="status" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'pagination2';
        $.ajax({

                url:"pagination2.php",  
                method:"POST",
                error: function(xhr, text){
                alert("Whoops! The request for new content failed");
                     }, 
                data:{page:page},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#load_data').html(data);
                }, 
           })  
      }  


      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(event) pagination
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var page = $(this).attr("id"); 
            load_data(page);
            history.pushState({page}, `Selected: ${page}`, `./selected=${page}`)
            return event.preventDefault();
      });

            window.addEventListener('popstate', e => {
            var page = $(this).attr("id");
            load_data(e.state.page);
            console.log('popstate error!');
    });
        history.replaceState({page: null}, 'Default state', './');
 });
```

Comment: What do you expect from `pagination2.php/page=2,3,4`? That does not look valid

Comment: @ Nico Haase  Example: when I am on page 5, I go to product detail, after that I'm not on 5 page,  I'm on page 1:) Working example `https://tysonlighting.com/lighting/?&paged=2`

Comment: @ Nico Haase I don't know if this is ajax or history.pushState